# Auto Layout: How to adjust label size so it doesn't cut off at baseline

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

Have a label with the text "Weight" in the label.

When I press "Update Frames", it keeps shrinking the label size so that when I run it, it cuts off the part of the letter "g" which hangs below the baseline. Auto Layout wants the height of the label to be 14, but if I increase it to 20, Auto Layout gives me a warning.

How can I increase the height of the label so that I can get the part of "g" below the baseline, and also tell Auto Layout to stop giving me warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you can do that in IB, but it can be done like this through code,

```
NSLayoutConstraint *const = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:yourLabel
                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                   toItem:nil
                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                               multiplier:1
                                                 constant:20];
```

and add it to your label.